# How to hide username and password from log4j logs when sent over http

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to hide the username and password from my log4j logs when i log an Http POST message that contains them. I have removed the real username and password in this example:

```
2015-10-07 11:19:41  DEBUG wire:72 - http-outgoing-3 >> "POST /login?IDToken1=<Username in plain text is seen here>&IDToken2=<Password in plain text is seen here> HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
```

I have a log4j.properties file which has the rootlogger set to DEBUG. 
I tried to use the following lines to only do logging on INFO level:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.client=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=INFO
```

but none of them works. I tried this though and it worked:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=INFO
```

The only problem with this is that all `http` logging on DEBUG level is hidden too. I really only want to hide the username and password if it's possible.
Either that or to fine tune the granularity so i can hide the message in the example above.

Is that possible to do?

Comment: How about using a file appender with a custom pattern layout that doesn't include the information? Or you could extend the appender to filter out the specific information. Or event a custom filter that discards that specific message (/login*)?

Comment: Hi,

EJP. It is logged by default on DEBUG level in the Apache http classes and i am logging a lot of other things using log4j so i can't really not log it. I tried to be specific and log headers, client and wire on INFO level but it did not work.

Stig Tore, i will have a look at your suggestions.

Thanks for your replies / Jan

Answer (score -2):

Here is the log4j conf. I'm using:

```
# (org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire)
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header = INFO
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content = INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient = INFO
```

Comment: What if user want to see the debug logs? Should they never do debugging?